# IE8 ADO warning when opening a record set with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, database, internet-explorer-8, ado

I have a few HTML pages that use javascript to run sql queries etc.  these html files are accessed from a share drive on the network.    this works perfectly in IE6.  My workplace is updating to IE8 and I now get the following warning:

"This Web site uses a data provider that may be unsafe. If you trust the Web site, click OK, otherwise click Cancel."

This is very annoying as every sql interaction results in this warning.

I have spent a lot of time researching and the solution seems to be that I need to add the site to my trusted sites list.  However, I am unable to do so due to group policy disabling access to IE settings, and my IT department says that they will not alter the trusted sites list.

Are there any other options? If I could somehow get a trusted certificate would that help? I have also researched other ways to try and run sql without javascript and without a web server but I didnt have much luck.

Answer (score 1):

you're getting the cross-domain alert because your accessing data on a different server. you can put them on the same server and that should fix your problem.'

regardless, and i mean this with all sincerity, you need to get up with your it department and have a little heart-to-heart; they're going to be wary of you and most likely dissmissive...do not let them dissuade you. be polite but be just as stubborn. and if you really want to be a dick about it, when they're up on their high horse telling you nay, you should question their expertise...particularly with user-agents. if they're converting from ie6 in 2012....there's no situation they can describe that makes that acceptable. i'm assuming your intranet was built specifically for ie6 and that'll be their main excuse.....dude ie7 came out in 2007. their excuse is five years old. furthermore....it's still weak sauce.

you and all of your coworkers can enjoy chrome if you add chrome frame to your installation. look it up. wow your it department.

lastly....you're a developer that is not allowed to choose browser, and the browser they grant you access to isn't even fully functional?   a)Quit b)Quit c)Quit

Answer (score 0):

[Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401672/albert) already talked you through it (*and how right he is*). Otherwise a solution could be to put a pass through server (somewhere in your network) between the client and database, e.g. using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) with an odbc library like [node-tds](http://cretz.github.com/node-tds/) or [tedious](http://pekim.github.com/tedious/).